# Selecting element with CSS and Capybara

Tags: html, css, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to select `td.col_4` within the following HTML structure using Capybara, but to no avail so far:

```
<div id="potentialResults">
  <div class="result">
    <table class="report">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col_1">
           <img original-title="Sources : Telephone Directory">
             <a href="#"><u>Name 1</u></a>
          </td>
          <td class="col_2"></td>
          <td class="col_3"></td>
          <td class="col_4">Address 1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    <table class="report">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col_1">
           <img original-title="Sources : Telephone Directory">
             <a href="#"><u>Name 2</u></a>
          </td>
          <td class="col_2"></td>
          <td class="col_3"></td>
          <td class="col_4">Address 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

 </div>
```

So at the moment to get the text `address 1` for `Name 1` I do this

```
page.find("#potentialResults > .result > .report > tbody > tr > td.col_1 > a", text: "Name 1", match: :first).find('td.col_4').text
```

But where I seem to be struggling is getting the same address but using the img data-attribute as my identifier

```
page.find("#potentialResults > .result > .report > tbody > tr > td.col_1 > img[original-title='Sources : Telephone Directory'] + td.col_4",  match: :first).text
```

But `td.col_4` isn't exactly adjacent in this example is it?

How else would I be able to get the text when stipulating that it has to be the first match?

Answer (score 0):

The css you're passing to your finders is way too lengthy.  It can be shortened without running into ambiguous results.

If you want to just simply get text from td.col_4, just do:

```
find('#potentialResults .col_4').text
```

If you want the address for 'Name 1', you need to first find that element, traverse up to the parent by a few levels, then find your way back down.  This is because the elements you are looking for are siblings, and Capybara doesn't really provide an easy way to find these:

```
find('#potentialResults .col_1 a', :text => 'Name 1').find(:xpath, '../../..').find('.col_4').text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldn't i still run into ambiguous issues if the name i am looking for exists in multiple places, which is why im using `match: :first`.. I didn't know you could flick between `xpath` and `css` so that's real handy. In the end i did find an xpath only solution but your answer is food for thought, thanks

Comment: I had assumed the names would be unique.  You could use [first](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method)